# Dynamically repositioning elements with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get the counterpart to selected element to position at the top of relevant elements BUT I would like to make sure that the "bottom" elements get below the selected one and not under it. If you look at the example you will get an idea about what I mean.

The semi working code example:

```js
$('.wrapper-2').on('click', '[class^="unique"]', function(e) {

  var selected = '#' + $(this).attr('class');

  $('.wrapper-1>div').each(function() {
    $(this).css({
      'background-color': 'orange',
      'position': 'relative'
    });
  });

  console.log($(selected).position());

  $(selected).css({
    'background-color': 'blue',
    'position': 'absolute',
    'top': '0px'
  });

});
```

```css
.wrapper {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #FFF;
}
.wrapper-1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
}
.wrapper-2 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 140px;
}
.wrapper-1 div {
    position: relative;
    width: 120px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: orange;
    margin: 10px;
}
.wrapper-2 div {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 120px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: grey;
    margin: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper wrapper-1">
  <div id="unique1">One</div>
  <div id="unique2">Two</div>
  <div id="unique3">Three</div>
  <div id="unique4">Four</div>  
</div>

<div class="wrapper wrapper-2">
  <div class="unique1">- 1 -</div>
  <div class="unique2">- 2 -</div>
  <div class="unique3">- 3 -</div>
  <div class="unique4">- 4 -</div>
</div>
```

UPDATED [FIDDLE THAT WORKS](https://jsfiddle.net/rzc1kqac/3/):

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple approach would be to add padding at the top of the container, to fill the space that would otherwise be taken by the first element in the list.  The others will sit beneath it as before:

```js
$('.wrapper-2').on('click', '[class^="unique"]', function(e) {

  var selected = $('#' + $(this).attr('class'));

  $('.wrapper-1>div').each(function() {
    $(this).css({
      'background-color': 'orange',
      'position': 'relative'
    });
  });

  console.log(selected.position());

  selected.css({
    'background-color': 'blue',
    'position': 'absolute',
    'top': '0px'
  });

  // ** this is the new bit
  //
  $('.wrapper-1').css('padding-top', '60px');
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #FFF;
}
.wrapper-1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}
.wrapper-2 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 140px;
}
.wrapper-1 div {
  position: relative;
  width: 120px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: orange;
  margin: 10px;
}
.wrapper-2 div {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 120px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper wrapper-1">
  <div id="unique1">One</div>
  <div id="unique2">Two</div>
  <div id="unique3">Three</div>
  <div id="unique4">Four</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper wrapper-2">
  <div class="unique1">- 1 -</div>
  <div class="unique2">- 2 -</div>
  <div class="unique3">- 3 -</div>
  <div class="unique4">- 4 -</div>
</div>
```

Comment: ah great,, I don't know why ion earth this didn't occur to me,, lol